# Slot-machine-style logotype stripe

Tags: jquery, ticker, graphical-logo

I am looking for a component to display affiliates' logotypes, preferably jQuery, then Flash, in a page-wide stripe (say: 800x100px). One that is fully automated, does not engage user operation and displays images much like a slot machine (one-armed bandit). So there would be probably 8 logotypes in a row, each of them changing almost at the same time.

Can anybody recommend one, please?

(Or maybe I'm missing a jargon call for it and my searches are in vain...)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's unlikely that you'll find third-party code which does what you want it to do. If you do, I would argue that the time and effort in tracking it down and then configuring or changing it to meet your requirements might be more constructively and satisfyingly put to taking on the problem yourself. If you solve it, and can abstract your work into something that others can use (a [jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for example), you could even release it on github so that others can benefit from it (assuming they come up with the correct search terms of course ;)).

Comment: I re-read my question and realized I did not make one thing clear enough: the strip would be divided into several slots each filled with one logotype, and they would change independently, although almost at the same time with a slide-in movement. So it's not about one image being changed at one time, but a set of images.

Comment: You should probably update your question. Depending on the exact requirements, the slideshow plugin approach might still work for you. You could have a row of image lists with a separate instance of the slideshow plugin acting on each list.

Answer (score 0):

I think here you can find scripts which can help you:

http://matthewlein.com/experiments/slots.html
http://www.eyecon.ro/slotmachine/